# Excluding Certain Rows Based On If They Have NA's For Other Rows

Tags: r, if-statement

So for my final paper, I'm replicating data from a dissertation that uses the FFCW data set. The FFCW involves various surveys. Part of the stipulations the author makes is that she includes people who have answered at least 3 of the 4 specific questions about parental stress. I need to replicate that in my filtering, but I don't know how to because I've been filtering based on certain values, not if certain values have been answered. Is it possible to exclude based on an ifelse statement? How could I write an exclusion for criteria like that, i.e. exclude a row if it answers less than 3 of the questions, but it doesn't matter which questions? Not excluding based on their values, but if they even answered a question.

I've tried excluding all NA for the variables or specific combinations of the variables, but I'm still not getting the same n as the dissertation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the optimal solution, but you could count the number of questions answered, and then exclude those less than a certain number:

```
rawData = data.frame(ID = letters[seq(6)], q1 = c(1,2,3,NA,5,6), q2 = c(1,NA,3,4,5,6), q3=c(1,2,3,NA,5,6), q4 = c(1,NA,NA,4,5,6))
qsAnswered = apply(rawData[,seq(2,5)], MARGIN=1, function(x){length(which(!is.na(x)))})
filteredData = rawData[which(qsAnswered >= 3),]
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but the problem is that when a question isn't answered for whatever reason, it's not always the same value. If the question isn't answered, they use values from -1 to -9, so if I use rowSums, I could be including a combination of 2 negative values, 2 positive values that add up to a certain number by accident.

Comment: Can you preprocess to convert the -1 to -9 values into NA?